# Converting triangle mesh polygon into square cells

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I have a triangle mesh polygon feature class.

[image]

I would like to convert it to raster-like cells but still as a polygon feature class using ArcGIS Pro.

This needs to be at 1m resolution

It is important to retain the attributes of the triangles.

I tried doing it like this:

1. Polygon to raster tool on the triangle mesh
2. Raster To Point
3. Create fishnet with input as the Raster
4. Feature to Polygon on fishnet layer using the layer from  Raster to Point as label features

However, this was still running after 24 hours.

Is there a better method to go about this?

Comment: Point to raster using point id. Raster to polygon. Steps 3,4.

Comment: Your image is too saturated to be useful. Instead of blue, try using a pale yellow, or a collection of pastels by attribute. Come to think of it, more details about the attribute(s) you seek to preserve are needed. Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to convert these triangles to squares where each1m x1m  square has the same values as the triangles.  Can you explain?

Comment: @GBG it is for a flood extent that needs to be smoothed. Smoothing the triangle mesh does not give as good looking results as smoothing squares.